# How to get jsp page data on java class

Tags: java, jsp

I am getting huge length data on finaldata.Tha data is going through url .if the data is too big then it will get error. beacuse url have limit to send data.
so what is alternative to send data to my java class .

This my function on my jsp page

```
function downloadAttachment(format){
    var alterTrans= GetXmlHttpObject();
    var finaldata=callRebuilder(format);
    alert("finaldata : "+finaldata);
    var url= "/jmax/settargetOutput.action?finalTargetTxt="+finaldata;
}
```

What is the alternative for sending data through url?

Comment: check out about spring mvc

Comment: use POST request so it ll not pass through URL and you can easily receive data in Servlet. Try google about post request to servet.

Comment: You can send and recieve data from JSP to java through AJAX..

Answer (score 0):

Please use form submission on that with `post`. Please use hidden tag for that value and submit the page. In that action class you will get from form.